# How can I fix these errors about not being able to find dependencies when compiling project in android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting these errors when I try and build my project, it looks like it thinks I have 2 of the same library, but I'm not sure why:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.inject:guice:4.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.inject:guice:4.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.inject:guice:4.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.inject:guice:4.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.inject:guice:4.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha02.
Open File
Show Details
```

**This is my build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.andydaykin.timer"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    dexOptions {
        // release & debug is in project animators
        matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.10
    sourceCompatibility 1.10
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation ('androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0') {
    force = true
}
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"

def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}
```

**This is my top level gradle build file:**

{

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

}

I think this error happened after an upgrade to android studio but I can't remember for sure. My android studio version now is 3.2.1. I was able to get this project to build previously.

Comment: maybe your gradle has been set to offline?

Comment: try adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` repository

Comment: I am also facing same problem let me know if you find any solution i will also do the same.

Comment: Gradle has not been set to offline, and I do have the maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } in the code above.

Comment: Are you able to make your `play-services-analytics` and `play-services-ads` use the same version number? Additionally, can you post your project-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: You should not need the allprojects{} section in your lower level build.gradle file. That's for the top level, which you already have.

Comment: @Andy : just to make sure your connection is not behind a firewall or proxy that might be blocking those services.

Comment: @Andy Just try invalidate and restart android studio. I got same problem when I update my android studio for androidx. May works for you

Comment: Yeah I've tried to invalidate and restart, unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: With @thenewbiecoder say that help also connect  with internet

Comment: Have you checked your language compatibility with your dependencies? try with lower java version once.

Comment: I've just resolved a very similar issue, so am wondering if you have a similar problem. My project had a few modules and with the change to AndroidStudio (Canary) and needed Gradle upgrade, I started getting a lot of odd symbol resolution errors. They were caused by the change in how symbol dependencies are made visible as compile/implementation/api directives have changed. 

I resolved mine by making sure the base application included compile time dependencies that previously could be seen in other modules/libraries. It wasn't easy to track them all down, which made this tricky to solve.

Answer (score 2):

In your **top level Gradle** file add class path for google service plugin.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

**you should check for your internet connection, proxy or firewall.**

**OR**

cross check to disable Gradle Offline by following.

Windows:

> Settings >Gradle >Disable Offline Work

Mac:

> Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment >Gradle >Disable Offline Work

[image]

Comment: I already had offline work disabled, the error is still happening with the change to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716633/8034839 and [React Native : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713098/react-native-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3) which might help
It is related to AndroidX migration.

Try below solution from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

**Migrate an existing project using Android Studio**

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting **Refactor** > **Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.
>
> If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your `gradle.properties` file:
>
> ```
> android.useAndroidX=true
> android.enableJetifier=true
> ```
>
> To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the android.useAndroidX flag to true and the android.enableJetifier flag to false.

Also, inside your **TOP-LEVEL** `build.gradle`, pull up the `google()` to top as below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // here
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        //google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have those 2 properties set. I'm still getting the same error with the change to the top level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

> I think this error happened after an upgrade to android studio

The problem just began when you changed **compile** into **implementation**.

Assume A,B and C are three modules and the relation between them are as follows

**C** > **B** > **A**   
 <sub>> Represents a dependency</sub>

When using **compile**, C can directly access A. But it is not possible when using **implementation**. There is **api** which will have the same effect as compile.

---

*Note: It is not recommended to use api everywhere. api and compile will make the compilation process slower because it will force to recompile all low level modules where implementation will recompile only required modules when a top level module is modified.*

Comment: I tried replacing all instances of implementation with api and got the same error message.

Comment: Do you have any modules other than app? Have you tried doing the same in there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 3+ and Gradle version 4.+ then maven is not needed.
Try removing

```
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
             }
```

and just have,

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()    
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move `google()` above all other things as below:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
 google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```