# React Native : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm making an android app using react native and this is the error I'm getting :

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fetch-blob'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-fetch-blob:classpath'.
       > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
         Required by:
             project :react-native-fetch-blob
```

I'm getting the following warnings also :

```
    > Configure project :app 
    WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
    It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
    Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
    To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

    > Configure project :react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box 
    WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
    It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
    WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
    Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
    To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
```

This is my build.gradle file :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }

            // jitpack repo is necessary to fetch ucrop dependency
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

This is my gradle wrapper distribution url :

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

I tried changing the order of different repositories and still getting the same error.

Comment: Would you please share the app build.gradle file here?

Comment: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30

Comment: This is a google issue, but need to wait for some time to bring the `google()` repo back to normal.

Comment: [Here's the google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) about this problem, it's a google repo problem, nothing to do until they fix it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 was removed from the jcenter repository.

Try adding this code to your top-level build.gradle file:

```
subprojects {project ->
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-fetch-blob')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen the workaround from google issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment44

Seeing your error logs:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fetch-blob'.
>     Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-fetch-blob:classpath'.
>     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.

You are still searching for AGP **2.2.3** for your project `:react-native-fetch-blob`.

For those **React Native** or **CordovaLib** projects that are with Android Gradle Plugin lower versions, e.g. 2.2.3, you can try to replace the `google()` with below `maven` style, and add the **android tools workaround**. So, modify your **top-level** `build.gradle` file as below for both `buildscripts` and `allprojects`:

```
buildscripts {
    repositories {

        // below is the workaround for android tools 
        maven {
            artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        // ... 
        jcenter()

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        // below is the workaround for android tools 
        maven {
            artifactUrls "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        // ... 
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Clean up your project and then perform a new Sync.

- Try "**File**"->"**Invalidate Caches / Restart ...**"
- Try to clean up your `.gradle` and `.idea` directory under your project root directory.

See below references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354236/8034839

---

**For the warnings:**

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Because you are using AGP (**A**ndroid **G**radle **P**lugin 3.2.1), the build configuration `compile` has changed to `implementation` and `api`. Just replace all the `compile` with `implementation` or `api` will let this warning disappear. See: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations for more details.

> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>       Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>       To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

This warning is just for your information, you can simply ignore it or remove `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'` from your `build.gradle` file to suppress this warning.