# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Please Help me!
After constructing a new `project`, I encountered the `following error` :

[image: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1]

new problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.sqlitedb"
      minSdkVersion 25
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
     release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-      optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:3.0.2'
}
```

Errors found:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>   Affected Modules: app

Comment: make your sdk configured with gradle

Comment: How make  sdk configured with gradle?

Comment: try the workaround here: [replace the google() with maven style, and add the android tools workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716633/8034839)

Comment: From File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try with **mavenCentral** like this.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
.....
..........
}
```

Comment: Thank's. Solved.But now this error:(Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 )  and (Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3)

Comment: please put full **build.gradle**  file by update your question.

Comment: add `google()` below of `jcenter()`

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin 
You can specify the plugin version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or the top-level build.gradle file. The plugin version applies to all modules built in that Android Studio project. The following example sets the plugin to version 3.3.0 from the build.gradle file