# 'Could not find com.android.tools.build: gradle : 4.2.2.'

Tags: react-native

am making an android app using react native and the error am getting is could not find the build gradle

here is the content in build gradle inside android studio.
the distrubution url is gradle 6.9.

````
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

      
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}```
have being trying to solve this for hours with no avail. please do help out
````

Comment: Replace`mavenCentral()` from `buildscript` -> `repositories ` with `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`.  Might Help

Comment: thanks,but  i tried it,and it did not resolve the error

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713098/react-native-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-2-3?rq=1 ?

Comment: yes ,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Place it in your `build.gradle` to replace `jcenter` in all your dependencies

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        def REPOSITORY_URL = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
                def url = repo.url.toString()
                if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
                    project.logger.lifecycle "Repository ${repo.url} replaced by $REPOSITORY_URL."
                    remove repo
                }
            }
        }
        maven {
            url REPOSITORY_URL
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```